# I am using react hooks on menu item. My first click does not do anything, subsequent clicks work as intended

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './menu.css';

const menuItems = [ 'Home', 'Rooms', 'Photos', 'About' ];

const MenuItems = () => {
    const [ toggle, setToggle ] = useState(false);
    const [ classOn, setClassOn ] = useState('');
    const [ hidden, setHidden ] = useState('hidden');

    function toggleOnMenu(event) {
        setToggle(!toggle);
        if (toggle) {
            setClassOn('on');
            setHidden('');
        } else {
            setClassOn('');
            setHidden('hidden');
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    return (
        // menu-section
        <div onClick={(event) => toggleOnMenu(event)} className={classOn + ' menu-section'} style={{}}>
            {/* menu-toggle */}
            <div className={classOn + ' menu-toggle'} style={{}}>
                {/* one */}
                <div className="one" style={{}} />
                {/* two */}
                <div className="two" style={{}} />
                {/* three */}
                <div className="three" style={{}} />
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul
                    role="navigation"
                    className={hidden}
                    style={{
                        // display: 'none'
                    }}
                >
                    {menuItems.map((menuItem) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={menuItem}>
                                <a href="/">{menuItem}</a>
                            </li>
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MenuItems;
```

I don't know what is the problem here. When you click the first time, nothing happens, but right after that it works as intended. Once you refresh the page back to the same problem.

So I think I have something wrong conceptually here. I already refactored the code to a working alternative, but if someone knows the reason why, I would greatly appreciate the help to fill this gap in my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

`setToggle(!toggle);` doesn't return the expected value in the first fire, you have to waiting the change then decide what you're doing by the new `toggle`, but `setToggle` doesn't accept second argument/callback.
To fix you have two options:

- use `useReducer()`
- change it using `useEffect()`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wondering about my refactored code here it is

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './menu.css';

const menuItems = [ 'Home', 'Rooms', 'Photos', 'About' ];

const MenuItems = () => {
    const [ toggle, setToggle ] = useState(false);

    function toggleOnMenu(event) {
        setToggle(!toggle);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    return (
        // menu-section
        <div onClick={(event) => toggleOnMenu(event)} className={(toggle ? 'on' : '') + ' menu-section'} style={{}}>
            {/* menu-toggle */}
            <div className={(toggle ? 'on' : '') + ' menu-toggle'} style={{}}>
                {/* one */}
                <div className="one" style={{}} />
                {/* two */}
                <div className="two" style={{}} />
                {/* three */}
                <div className="three" style={{}} />
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul role="navigation" className={toggle ? '' : 'hidden'} style={{}}>
                    {menuItems.map((menuItem) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={menuItem}>
                                <a href="/">{menuItem}</a>
                            </li>
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MenuItems;
```

Comment: The refactored code doesn't have anything to do with the answer you marked as correct!.

Answer (score 0):

Above implementation violates the exhaustive dependencies rule: every value referenced inside the function should also appear in the dependencies array. This is required to ensure that values inside a callback are always up-to-date and avoid any bugs related to that.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import './menu.css';

const menuItems = [ 'Home', 'Rooms', 'Photos', 'About' ];

const MenuItems = () => {
    const [ toggle, setToggle ] = useState(false);

  const toggleOnMenu = useCallback(() => setToggle(state => !state), [toggle]);

    return (
        // menu-section
        <div onClick={toggleOnMenu} className={(toggle ? 'on' : '') + ' menu-section'} style={{}}>
            {/* menu-toggle */}
            <div className={(toggle ? 'on' : '') + ' menu-toggle'} style={{}}>
                {/* one */}
                <div className="one" style={{}} />
                {/* two */}
                <div className="two" style={{}} />
                {/* three */}
                <div className="three" style={{}} />
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul role="navigation" className={toggle ? '' : 'hidden'} style={{}}>
                    {menuItems.map((menuItem) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={menuItem}>
                                <a href="/">{menuItem}</a>
                            </li>
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MenuItems;
```